# testCoverageEnabled = false Crashes App

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I have a situation where I cannot debug local variables because in my gradle file I have `testCoverageEnabled true`. A number of posts have correctly suggested that this should be set to `false`. The issue I am having is that when I do that, my app crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app, PID: 22172
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyAppLog.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:14)
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.Log.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.setLevel(Unknown Source:0)
                      at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.setupLogging(MyApp.java:171)
                      at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:71)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6056)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-FmWSRcYONdAudVVemfy_Bw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-FmWSRcYONdAudVVemfy_Bw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-FmWSRcYONdAudVVemfy_Bw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:14) 
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.setLevel(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.setupLogging(MyApp.java:171) 
                      at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:71) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6056) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I am assuming that this has something to do with `Jacoco`, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue was because we are using `jacoco` for our using testing:

```
 testImplementation 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128:runtime'
```

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the `jacoco` library that I was using at runtime:

```
 implementation 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128:runtime'
```

The key is to make sure that you use the *EXACT* same library you are using in the app.